# Optional chaining like syntax but cant any resource to explain

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, optional-chaining

I have just come across

`this.person!.name`

in my codebase, previously I have seen `this.person?.name` which is optional chaining, but I have never seen `!` be used nor can I find any resource to explain it's use, can anyone shed any light on it?

Comment: It means that according to Typescript, `this.person` can be null or undefined, but the developer who coded this know that in this specific case, the value can't be null or undefined, so he added `!` to remove the warning about nullability

Comment: It's slightly worrying that you tagged this [tag:typescript] code in *your codebase* as [tag:javascript].